# JS - getElementById not working. Firefox throws: Syntax Error Chrome throws: Unexpected }

Tags: javascript, forms, this, getelementbyid

Validating a form is not working. Below you see the code and error message.
Don't think its a problem with JS, Chrome and Firefox point to the HTML part.
See screenshot I made from Firefox' Firebug.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div>Enter your state code:<input id="state" name="state" type="text" size="2" onblur="isStateOk(this.document.getElementById("state_help"));"/>        
<span id="state_help"></span></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function isStateOk(inputField, helpId) {        // See if the input value contains any text

    return editNodeText (/^A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]$/, inputField.value, helpId, "Enter a State Code in Uppercase (Ex.NY, PA, CA)");
}
```

Note: `eclipse` show a red dotted line under: ("`state_help`"). Maybe the `id` of the `span` cannot be found at all? I do get code assistance though when start typing `state_`

UPDATE: JAVASCRIPT FILE: NEW ERROR MESSAGE POINTING TO THE FIRST FUNCTION IN THIS FILE BELOW:

```
function editNodeText(regex, input, helpId, helpMessage) {        // See if the visitor entered the right information

    if (!regex.test(input)) {          // If the wrong information was entered, warn them

        if (helpId != null)

            while (helpId.firstChild) // Remove any warnings that may exist

                helpId.removeChild(helpId.firstChild);

                helpId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(helpMessage)); // Add new warning

                return false;
    } else {          // If the right information was entered, clear the help message

        if (helpId != null){

            while (helpId.firstChild) // Remove any warnings that may exist

                helpId.removeChild(helpId.firstChild);
        }

        return true;

    }   
}




//inputField – ID Number for the html text box
//helpId – ID Number for the child node I want to print a warning in
//See if the input value contains any text
function isTheFieldEmpty(inputField, helpId) {          

    return editNodeText(/^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,15}\s?[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,15}\s?[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,15}/, inputField.value, helpId, "Please enter a valid name.");
} // inputField.value – Value typed in the html text box



function isAddressOk(inputField, helpId) {        // See if the input value contains any text

    return editNodeText(/^[A-Za-z0-9\.\' \-]{5,30}$/, inputField.value, helpId, "Enter a Street (Ex.1234 Main St.)");
}



function isStateOk(inputField, helpId) {        // See if the input value contains any text

    return editNodeText (/^A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[AU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY]$/, inputField.value, helpId, "Enter a State Code in Uppercase (Ex.NY, PA, CA)");
}



function isPhoneOk(inputField, helpId) {        // See if the input value contains any text

    return editNodeText(/^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$/, inputField.value, helpId, "Enter a Phone Number (Ex.412-828-3000)");
}



function isEmailOk(inputField, helpId) {        // See if the input value contains any text

    return editNodeText(/^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/, inputField.value, helpId, "Enter an Email (Ex. cimdata@javascript.de)");

}
```

Comment: You are not passing `inputField` to the function `isStateOk`, which, in turn is passing it to `editNodeText`. In your `onblur="..."` call, you need to pass 2 parameters.

Comment: Thanks, its working now with this: `onblur="isTheFieldEmpty(this, document.getElementById('name_help'));"`Will you answer this question that I can mark you answer as the correct one?

Comment: Nice to know that you fixed it. Please mark @alex-k's answer as the correct one he was the first to answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes for JS strings contained within an html attribute's double quotes or the result is unparseable;

From:

```
onblur="isStateOk(this.document.getElementById("state_help"));"/>
```

to:

```
onblur="isStateOk(this.document.getElementById('state_help'));"/>
```

Comment: Also, replace `this.document` to `document`.

Comment: Changed it to `'` but get another error message now: `TypeError: this.document is undefined 
isStateOk(this.document.getElementById("state_help"));` Why is the error message still showing `"`? I did reload the page.

Comment: `this` in the elements event is the element itself so just `document.getElementById('state_help')`

Comment: Have removed `this` but now I get another error message, this time pointing to `editNodeText()` (See update to my original post). Exact error: `TypeError: helpId is undefined helpId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(helpMessage));`